# AoT + Webpack + json dynamic require

Tags: json, angular, webpack, loader, angular2-aot

After installing the AoT plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack) for webpack, `dynamic requires` no longer work:

```
// Example that used to work
public getJson<T>(fileName: String): T {
    return require(`../../${fileName}_${this.lang}.json`);
}
```

With the standard `ts-loader` or `awesome-typescript-loader` etc, `dynamic requires` worked and webpack bundled the `json` files into the main `app` bundle. However, with the AoT/Webpack plugin the json files are not bundled at all. I don't even think the `aot loader` iterates over the json files anymore.

Any ideas how to get this to work again? Thanks.

**Info:**

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3306

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4153

**Update:**

Works somewhat with `SystemJS -> System.import()` but erratically
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6629#issuecomment-336411537

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround is to use `System.import()` to build load and bundle the dynamic files then use the standard webpack mechanism to load the actual files:

```
    public getLazyFiles<T>(somePath: string): T {
        /* AoT Hack - causes the AoT to find and prepare the dynamically loaded files */
        System.import(`../../${somePath}_${this.someSuffix}.json`);
        /* ------- */
        // This is then used by webpack to actually load the files
        return require(`../../${somePath}_${this.someSuffix}.json`);
    }
```

Why this workaround is needed is explained here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6629#issuecomment-336478854